# Keeping the correct style on text retrieval

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am making an application similar to a chat. For that purpose I have two JTextPanes, one where I'm writing and one that displays messages. This is the code that handles the transferring of text from input to display :

```
                String input = textPane.getText();
                if(!input.endsWith("\n")){
                    input+="\n";
                }
                StyledDocument doc = displayPane.getStyledDocument();
                int offset = displayPane.getCaretPosition();
                textPane.setText("");
                try {
                    doc.insertString(offset, input, set);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ChatComponent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

The problem is that if i have colour on some words of the input text , the output is all coloured . So the colour is applied to all of the text when moved to display(while displayed correctly on input). Any suggestions on how i can move text properly?

Notice that same happens with other format as bold , italic etc

Comment: Answered by @StanislavL
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040294/keeping-the-format-on-text-retrieval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved by merging the document models of the two panes. The solution is in this question: [Keeping the format on text retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040294/keeping-the-format-on-text-retrieval)

Answer (score 6):

```
The text is already formatted on the input JTextPane . What i need to do 
is transfer it as it is on a different JTextPane without having to check 
the different style options
```

example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class Fonts implements Runnable {

    private String[] fnt;
    private JFrame frm;
    private JScrollPane jsp;
    private JTextPane jta;
    private int width = 450;
    private int height = 300;
    private GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    private StyledDocument doc;
    private MutableAttributeSet mas;
    private int cp = 0;
    private Highlighter.HighlightPainter cyanPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.cyan);
    private Highlighter.HighlightPainter redPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.red);
    private Highlighter.HighlightPainter whitePainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.white);
    private int _count = 0;
    private int _lenght = 0;

    public Fonts() {
        jta = new JTextPane();
        doc = jta.getStyledDocument();
        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height, width));
        frm = new JFrame("awesome");
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frm.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.setLocation(100, 100);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
        jta.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        fnt = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        mas = jta.getInputAttributes();
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < fnt.length; i++) {
            StyleConstants.setBold(mas, false);
            StyleConstants.setItalic(mas, false);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(mas, fnt[i]);
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(mas, 16);
            dis(fnt[i]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StyleConstants.setBold(mas, true);
            dis(fnt[i] + " Bold");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StyleConstants.setItalic(mas, true);
            dis(fnt[i] + " Bold & Italic");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StyleConstants.setBold(mas, false);
            dis(fnt[i] + " Italic");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        jta.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }

    public void dis(String s) {
        _count++;
        _lenght = jta.getText().length();
        try {
            doc.insertString(cp, s, mas);
            doc.insertString(cp, "\n", mas);
        } catch (Exception bla_bla_bla_bla) {
            bla_bla_bla_bla.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (_count % 2 == 0) {
            try {
                jta.getHighlighter().addHighlight(1, _lenght - 1, cyanPainter);
            } catch (BadLocationException bla_bla_bla_bla) {
            }
        } else if (_count % 3 == 0) {
            try {
                jta.getHighlighter().addHighlight(1, _lenght - 1, redPainter);
            } catch (BadLocationException bla_bla_bla_bla) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                jta.getHighlighter().addHighlight(1, _lenght - 1, whitePainter);
            } catch (BadLocationException bla_bla_bla_bla) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Fonts fs = new Fonts();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting but Im not sure if its helpful for my case. You seem to create the string ,format it, and send it for display. I am trying to copy a formatted string from the JTextPane , and send it to another JTextPane. Ill try to see if I can make use of you example

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), I really don't know how you adding colour to the text on your JTextPane, but hopefully this method might sort things out for you :

```
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

private void appendToTextPane(String name, Color c, String f)
{
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, f);

    int len = Client.nPane.getDocument().getLength();

    textPane.setCaretPosition(len);
    textPane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, true);
    textPane.replaceSelection(name);
}
```

With this  you can give a different `Color` and `Font` to each `String literal` that will be added to your JTextPane.

Hope this new Code might help you in some way :

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class TextPaneTest extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    private JTextPane tPane1;
    private JTextPane tPane2;
    private JButton button;

    public TextPaneTest()
    {
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);            

        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLUE);
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");      

        tPane1 = new JTextPane();
        tPane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        tPane1.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false); // Add these settings to the other JTextPane also

        tPane2 = new JTextPane();
        tPane2.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false); // Mimic what the other JTextPane has       

        button = new JButton("ADD TO THE TOP JTEXTPANE");
        button.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    tPane1.setText(tPane2.getText());
                }
            });

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        topPanel.add(tPane1);
        topPanel.add(tPane2);
        bottomPanel.add(button);

        pack();
        tPane2.requestFocusInWindow();
        setVisible(true);   
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    new TextPaneTest();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: The text is already formatted on the input JTextPane . What i need to do is transfer it as it is on a different JTextPane without having to check the different style options.