# JTextPane content never updates - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I've my pasted my source code [here](http://pastebin.com/qPrY6xhh).  The idea is to collect error messages and warnings in an application where each message is a paragraph with each paragraph describing parts of text with attributes. No matter, what I do the textpane would not display any text - I guess I have got something basic going wrong here. I can use some thoughts - thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Better post a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), since the code you are referring to, is not complete in any way. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you have got issue with [Concurency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), Swing is single threaded all changes from background task should be invoked EDT,

2) better would be initialize those code from [Swingworker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or [Runnble#Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022901/714968),

3) if you don't want to solve that your GUI will be unresponsive or freeze durring this task, then wrap output to the `Document` inside `invokeLater`

Comment: I think you mean unresponsive nor unresponsible ;)

Comment: I tried invoking the method that writes to the textpane from inside a runnable in SwingUtilities.invokeLater - it did not work :(

Answer (score 3):

All GUI changes need to be made through the use of the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method. This will place what you need on the EDT which then executes and displays your text on the screen.

Comment: doesn't work with SwingUtilities.invokeLater :( - the textpane never gets updated.