# Highlighting line of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to highlight multiple lines of a JTextArea subclass (not selected). Although I want to highlight the whole line and not just the text each line contains. I got this working but it only highlights text :

```
DefaultHighlighter h = (DefaultHighlighter)textArea.getHighlighter(
    try {
            int start = textArea.getLineStartOffset(blockedLine);
            int end = textArea.getLineEndOffset(blockedLine);
            DefaultHighlightPainter redHighlight = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
            h.addHighlight(start, end, redHighlight);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

How can I highlight the whole line instead of just the text ? I am using an open source library for the text area so getting a JTextPane or other component is not an option (using rysntaxtextarea library).

Comment: Your code works for me using JDK6_7 on XP. The key is the `end` value. When I use `end` the entire line is highlighted. When I use `end - 1` only the text is highlighted. So you need to make sure the newline charater is included in the highlight. Maybe try using `end + 1`? If you still have problems then post your SSCCE, maybe this is a version/platform issue.

Comment: @camickr s/he use derivate of JTextArea by Fifesoft,

Comment: changing the end offset will just make the highlight go one line bellow I would guess. Ill check it tho.

Comment: Tried the `end` idea with the default Swing JTextArea on JDK6_31 on Vista, and it never highlights the whole line: when I highlight up to the `\n` character, when the highlight includes the `\n` character and some character on the next line, when the `\n` is exactly the last character included in the range, when the highlight range is only the `\n` character (in this case no visual difference is observed). In all those cases the area to the right of the last character on the line remains white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [JTextPane / JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), these `JTextComponents` can be decorated and supporting styled Text, to the `JTextPane / JEditorPane` you can add any `JComponent` e.g. `Icon`... ), example for [HighlightPainter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022901/714968)

Comment: I am using RSyntaxTextArea since I want to write java code so changing component type is not an option. :/ 
http://javadoc.fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/

Answer (score 0):

The idea from @camickr's [LinePainter.java](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/line-painter/) applies here: implement [`Highlighter.HighlightPainter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.HighlightPainter.html), getting its `paint(..)` method to go outside of the `bounds` that it is given, painting a rectangle of the same height and full width.