# How to access all fonts of a font family with Swing

Tags: java, macos, swing, fonts, awt

My installation of OS X 10.8 comes pre-installed with 11 fonts in the family *Helvetica Neue*. I'm trying to find a way to access the fonts with styles like *medium* or *condensed*, which cannot be represented by the bit-mask values `Font.BOLD` and `Font.ITALIC`.

`GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()` returns `Font` objects for all these fonts but applying them using `JLabel.setFont()` seems to only use the styles representable with the mentioned bit-mask. This is shown on the left in the screenshot below, which compares it to a sample of all fonts when they are used in *TextEdit*.

The same happens if a `Font` object is constructed using the font's full name or its PostScript name.

Is there a way to use all those fonts, either by applying it to a *Swing* component or when painting to a `Graphics2D` (or `Graphics`) instance?

[image: Output from the Swing application on the left, sample of all fonts on the right.]

Below is the code I used to produce the dialog in the above screenshot.

```
package fahrplan;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FontsMain {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        for (Font i : e.getAllFonts()) {
            String name = i.getFontName();

            if (name.startsWith("HelveticaNeue")) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(name);

                label.setFont(i.deriveFont(18f));

                contentPane.add(label);
            }
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fonts");
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: [you can to test with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9022901/714968)

Comment: Suggest running with normalized names `getFontName(Locale.ENGLISH)`, `getFontFamily(Locale.ENGLISH)`. Fontname is composed from family+style description. In a `Font` subclass you may manage additional style classification, basically rework `Font.decode()` with normalized style description. Your question should be answered by filtering Fonts from the graphics environment with matching family name.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
int size=12, style=0;

GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
final Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts();
for(int i=0; i<fonts.length; i++)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(Font[i].getName);
        label.setFont(new Font(Font[i].getName, size, style));
        contentPane.add(label);
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The only difference in your code that I can spot right now is that you use a font size of 12 pt instead of 18. I don't think that's making a difference. ;) On a second note, did you look at the screenshot in my question?

Comment: I believe you! I since found out that this only happens for fonts for which multiple styles are stored in the same `.dfont` file, which us unique the OS X. I'm still looking for a way to use all those styles on a Mac.

Comment: This actually does not compile. First of all, Font[i] is not going to work, you probably mean fonts[i]. Also, the correct constructor is Font(name, style, size). In your code, the style would be set to 12 and size is set to 0. Thirdly, this is not an answer to the question.